# Symfony redirect web directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, symfony

i am a newbie of symfony, following a guide i had a working project test (contains only default page and lucky number, an example)

in 127.0.0.1:8000 it works perfectly, so i decide to upload in my server but i had a bad surprise

in the main folder of project dosnt works
http://www.andreapigliafreddo.it/test/symfony/
just in web directory it works
/test/symfony/web/
/test/symfony/web/lucky/number

how i can fix this? in test/symfony/ there is not .htaccess, and in test/symfony/web/ there is .htaccess with:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not     resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
# If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
# project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
# resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
# work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
# the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
# (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
# rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
# endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
# redirect -> request -> ...).
# So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
# to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
# environment variable, you have 2 choices:
# - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
# - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
#   following RewriteCond (best solution)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
    # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
            # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
            # and the generated links can still be used.
            RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
            # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
```

thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

Symfony web server documentation is here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

You need to specify the DocumentRoot directive to the `web/` folder.
I noticed you set the DirectoryIndex directive; I don't think you normally need to set that.

You can also take a look at [my Apache/Symfony blog](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/05/11/apache-symfony-on-rhel/) for reference. It should be fairly straight forward.